# Ansible compare fact with list

Tags: ansible

I try to compare a model from the ios_facts module with my list "new_models" but so far I couldn't find any good solution for that.

My list:

```
---
#
new_models:
  - name: WS-C3650-48PS #1 
  - name: WS-C3750X-48P #2 
  - name: C9200-48P #3
  - name: C9200L-24P-4G #
```

My playbook:

```
tasks:
  
    - name: Check facts
      ios_facts:
        gather_subset: hardware

    - name: Check switch model
      debug: 
       msg: "{{ ansible_net_model }}"
      register: switch_model
      
    - name: Remove file
      file:
        path: /root/ansible/pb-outputs/ios_counters/{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt
        state: absent
     
    - name: Create file for new model switches
      lineinfile:
        path: /root/ansible/pb-outputs/ios_counters/{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt
        line: "1"
        create: yes
      loop: "{{ new_models }}"
      when: switch_model.msg == item.name

    - name: Clear range of counters
      ios_command:
        commands:
          - command: clear counters gigabitEthernet {{ start }}/{{ middle }}/{{ item }}
            prompt: Clear "show interface" counters on this interface \[confirm\]
            answer: y
      with_sequence: start="{{ ifacefrom }}" end="{{ ifaceto }}"
      when: "{{ lookup('file', '/root/ansible/pb-outputs/ios_counters/{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt') }} == 1"
```

I also know I shouldn't use J2 inside conditionals but this was the only way it worked for me so far but I want to find a better solution for this. Sorry, I'm fairly new to ansible.

Would it be possible to combine with_items and with_sequence into one loop? I tried this too but I couldnt figure out the syntax for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, what I understand is that you would like to have a condition on the `ios_command` task to only execute if the `switch_model.msg` is in the list of `new_models`.

If so, you can use the [set_fact module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/set_fact_module.html) to extract the `name` attribute from the `new_models` list, so that a comparison can be directly made like `when: item in list`.

**Using `json_query()`:**

```yaml
- name: get the model names into new_model_names var
  set_fact:
    new_model_names: "{{ new_models | json_query('[].name') }}"
```

**OR Using `map()`:**

```yaml
- name: get the model names into new_model_names var
  set_fact:
    new_model_names: "{{ new_models | map(attribute='name') | list }}"
```

This will give us a list with only the value of name in `new_model_names`:

```json
"new_model_names": [
  "WS-C3650-48PS",
  "WS-C3750X-48P",
  "C9200-48P",
  "C9200L-24P-4G"
]
```

Now the comparison will be easy, i.e. `when: switch_model.msg in new_model_names`. This should eliminate the need to delete/create a file for this purpose.

The playbook can now just have:

```yaml
    - name: Check switch model
      debug: 
       msg: "{{ ansible_net_model }}"
      register: switch_model

    - name: get the model names into new_model_names var
      set_fact:
        new_model_names: "{{ new_models | json_query('[].name') }}"

    - name: Clear range of counters
      ios_command:
        commands:
          - command: clear counters gigabitEthernet {{ start }}/{{ middle }}/{{ item }}
            prompt: Clear "show interface" counters on this interface \[confirm\]
            answer: y
      with_sequence: start="{{ ifacefrom }}" end="{{ ifaceto }}"
      when: switch_model.msg in new_model_names
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution but would this also be possible without converting new_models into json?

Comment: Its not converting into JSON, it just extracts the `name' key from your list of dicts and makes it a simple YAML list/array.

Comment: Basically, its the same as `new_models | map(attribute='name') | list`. (answer updated)

Comment: Thanks a lot, "new_models | map(attribute='name') | list" solved my problem. I also tried to do it with map(attribute='name') but obviously I did something wrong